# Restore an iPod nano (1st gen.) to older firmware version

Tags: windows, firmware, ipod

I have an old iPod nano (1st. generation) from 2005. I updated the firmware to the latest version 1.3.1 and it has all kinds of problems for me. Random reboots, garbled images, etc...

How can I restore it to an older firmware version? iTunes won't let me. I tried downloading an old restore software from Apple which has the firmware version 1.2 but when I start it, it only tells me to use iTunes and quits.

I'm on Windows XP.

Comment: To solve this problem the user will need to use his computer, and therefore I consider it computer related.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for you and here is what I've found:

[iPod firmware 1.1.3](http://support.apple.com/downloads/iPod_Updater_2005_11_17)

A little forum talk about "how to downgrade" [here](http://www.ipodwizard.net/showthread.php?t=14712&highlight=nano+1.0)

And a comment from a user:

> You should be able to restore back to the 1.0 firmware using the ipod updater, when you run it just use the option to RESTORE IPOD to factory settings. It will format your nano so you will lose all the music on there
>
> The only thing I don't know is if the latest 2nd Generation Nanos will run the earlier 1G firmwares?
>
> If you nano defiinately only has the 1.1 firmware on it (1.2 if the latest) do not use itunes to update as I don't think you will be able to rollback.
>
> I'm not a nano expert but I would recommend you have a good read of ipodwizard.net as the forum there is where you will find all the answers you need.
>
> Messing with your firmware could easily result in a dead ipod !!

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it works the same way as the iPhone. If you have a copy of the firmware onyour local drive, start up iTunes and connect your ipod. You should have an option to restore your iphone on the home screen. Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and it will allow you to browse for the firmware you want to load. From there the process will be managed by iTunes.